# Using the Normal Approximation to the Poisson Distribution, where appropiate, If X ~ Po(30) find P(X=<31)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

P(X =< 31)

Z = X - μ/σ

= 31-30/30^1/2

= 0.183

-> Φ(0.183)

= 0.5726

*The Answer is 0.608*

Comment: Don't know where I went wrong :/

Comment: You shouldn't write $X-\mu/\sigma$ if you mean $(X-\mu)/\sigma.$ (But that's not why you got a wrong answer; see my answer below.)

Comment: As with your prior question, the issue is the continuity correction.  This always arises when you approximate a discrete process by a continuous one.

Comment: Michael Hardy; Silly of me. Lulu; Getting used to using the CC

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\Pr(X\le31) = \Pr(X<32).$ So do you use $\dfrac{31-30}{\sqrt{30}}$ or $\dfrac{32-30}{\sqrt{30}}\text{?}$

They are both approximations. In this situation just using the number halfway between those -- that is called a "continuity correction":
$$
\Phi\left( \frac{ 31.5 - 30}{\sqrt{30}} \right) \approx 0.6079.
$$

Comment: The _exact_ value from R statistical software is given by `ppois(31, 30)`, which returns 0.618643.